# Maximum Priority, Message TTL, and Dead Letter Exchange in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

1. I want to use Message TTL and Dead Letter Exchange to implement a countdown functionality.
2. I want to set a Message TTL for a message but not consume it immediately. Instead, I want it to expire and enter the dead letter queue. I intend to listen to the dead letter queue and consume the message to achieve this purpose.
3. I've noticed that the queue operates on a first-in-first-out basis, and it only checks the expiration of the message at the front of the queue. If the expiration time of the front message is long and it doesn't expire, it causes the entire queue to be blocked. Even if the messages behind it expire, they will remain blocked until the front message expires and becomes a dead letter.
4. I'm thinking whether it's possible to use the 'Maximum Priority' property. By setting the property, messages with shorter expiration times could be assigned a higher priority, while those with longer expiration times could be assigned a lower priority. This way, the intention is to have messages approaching expiration become dead letters sooner due to their higher priority.

In RabbitMQ, does the Maximum Priority property place messages with higher priority at the front of the queue？

1. Here is my train of thought:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrfSK.png)
2. Here is my code：

```java
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class DeadLetterExchangeConfig {

    @Bean
    public Queue normalQueue(){
        return QueueBuilder.durable("dlx.normal.queue").ttl(200000).deadLetterExchange("dlx.dlx.exchange").deadLetterRoutingKey("mimi").maxPriority(10).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue dlxQueue(){
        return QueueBuilder.durable("dlx.dlx.queue").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue lazyQueueTest(){
        return QueueBuilder.durable("lazy.test.queue").lazy().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Exchange normalExchange(){
        return ExchangeBuilder.directExchange("dlx.normal.exchange").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Exchange dlxExchange(){
        return ExchangeBuilder.directExchange("dlx.dlx.exchange").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding bingDlxNormal(){
        return BindingBuilder.bind(normalQueue()).to(normalExchange()).with("sangbiao").noargs();
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding bingDlxDlx(){
        return BindingBuilder.bind(dlxQueue()).to(dlxExchange()).with("mimi").noargs();
    }
}
```

```java
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class TestMQController {
    @GetMapping("/test/testDlx")
    public String testDlx(){
        DlxVo dlxVo = new DlxVo();
        dlxVo.setName("long");
        dlxVo.setStart(System.currentTimeMillis());
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("dlx.normal.exchange", "sangbiao", dlxVo, new MessagePostProcessor() {
            @Override
            public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws AmqpException {
                message.getMessageProperties().setExpiration("20000");
                message.getMessageProperties().setPriority(1);
                return message;
            }
        });
        return String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    @GetMapping("/test/testDlx1")
    public String testDlx1(){
        DlxVo dlxVo = new DlxVo();
        dlxVo.setName("short");
        dlxVo.setStart(System.currentTimeMillis());
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("dlx.normal.exchange", "sangbiao", dlxVo, new MessagePostProcessor() {
            @Override
            public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws AmqpException {
                message.getMessageProperties().setExpiration("1000");
                message.getMessageProperties().setPriority(5);
                return message;
            }
        });
        return String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
public class TestMQListener {
    @RabbitListener(queues = "dlx.dlx.queue")
    public void dlxExample(DlxVo dlxVo){
        Long start = dlxVo.getStart();
        String name = dlxVo.getName();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        log.info("{} get message:{}ms",name,(end - start)/1000);
    }
}
```

3. I first call /test/testDlx and then call /test/testDlx1.
4. But the consumer receives the message 20 seconds later.

```
2024-01-09T21:08:46.868+08:00  INFO 2452 --- [ntContainer#2-1] o.c.t.a.p.mqExample.TestMQListener       : short get message:18ms
2024-01-09T21:08:46.874+08:00  INFO 2452 --- [ntContainer#2-1] o.c.t.a.p.mqExample.TestMQListener       : long get message:20ms
```

5.I initially thought that Maximum Priority would place messages with higher priority at the front of the queue.

So, I expected to receive 'short get message: 1s' after 1 second and 'long get message: 20s' after 20 seconds.But why is the result inconsistent with my expectations?